# I am getting the trait bound `T: sns_pub::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to serialize a stuct with a generic member I get the error 'equired because of the requirements on the impl of `sns_pub::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` for `sns_pub::Message<T>`

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound(
serialize = "T: Serialize",
deserialize = "T: Deserialize<'de>",
))]
struct Message<T> {
    topic: String,
    message_id: String,
    created_date: DateTime<Utc>,
    message: T,
    subject: String
}
let msg = String::from("TEST_MESSAGE"); 
let message = Message {
             topic: self.topic.clone(),
             message_id: id.to_string(),
             created_date: now,
             subject: self.subject.clone(),
             message: msg
         };
let filename = format!("{}/{}_{}", self.folder_path, prefix, id);
let mut file = File::create(filename.clone())?;
 file.write_all(serde_yaml::to_string(&message)?.as_str())?;
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: sns_pub::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/sns_pub.rs:57:46
    | 
43  | impl<T> SnsPub<T> for DiskSnsPub {
    |      - help: consider restricting this bound: `T: sns_pub::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` ... 
57  |  file.write_all(serde_yaml::to_string(&message)?.as_str())?;
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^ the trait `sns_pub::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `T`
    |     ::: /home/moharaza/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde_yaml-0.8.11/src/ser.rs:421:8
    | 
421 |     T: ser::Serialize,
    |              -------------- required by this bound in `serde_yaml::ser::to_string`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `sns_pub::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_Message::_serde::Serialize` for `sns_pub::Message<T>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is missing *a lot* of information, and the error is actually caused by code that you didn't provide. This is why it's important to provide a [reprex].

However, I can guess some of the code is actually from a method of `Message`, since it uses `self`. What you have missed is to but bounds on `T` for the impl block that defines the method:

```
impl<T> Message<T>
where
    T: Serialize + for<'de> Deserialize<'de>,
{
     /// methods go here 
{
```

I know this because the error message already tells you pretty much this exactly.